# Specify Word Separators in WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm, delimiter, cpu-word, separator

In Sublime Text preferences, there is a "word_separators" property that allows you to specify a set of characters that separate different words.

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

This allows you to control what is selected when you double click on a certain piece of code.

**Is there something similar for WebStorm?** I would like to remove the hyphen from the list so a string such as "my-hyphen-word" is entirely selected when it is double-clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no such settings; please vote for [IDEA-155523](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155523).
Note that there is a 'Select whole CSS indentifiers on double click' option (`Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys`) that controls the double-click behavior in CSS

Comment: but even this is not working fine.
this option only works in `.css` and no way to turn it into a `.html`

Comment: I just added a similar feature request, but instead of just identifiers, it's also regarding CSS values (to treat them normally instead of different from comments). e.g. Double clicking on `12px` should select `12px` and not just `12` or `px` separately (this is only the case in values, but not elsewhere). https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49485